# (Symfony 4) Unable to access a class installed in my vendor folder

Tags: symfony, directory, vendor

I have installed the Liip bundle, and the class that I need is clearly available in my container, as here are the results of my debug:container command:

```
$ bin/console debug:container
liip_imagine.service.filter       Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService
```

Just to show you that it is there, here is a picture of my folder structure:

[image]

Here is the code that I use to access it in my controller:

```
public function saveProfileEditAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $imagine = $this
        ->container
        ->get('liip_imagine.service.filter');
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
The "liip_imagine.service.filter" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
```

I guess I need to know how to make this public?

Here is what my yaml file looks like:

```
liip_imagine :
    # configure resolvers
    resolvers :
        # setup the default resolver
        default :
            # use the default web path
            web_path : ~
    # your filter sets are defined here
    filter_sets :
        # use the default cache configuration
        cache : ~
        # the name of the "filter set"
        my_thumb :
            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            quality : 75
            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters :
                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }
                thumb_square :  { size : [300, 300], mode : outbound }
                thumb_rectangle_md : { size : [670, 400], mode : outbound }
                thumb_hd : { size : [1920, 1080], mode : outbound }
                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                background : { size : [124, 94], position : center, color : '#000000' }
```

Comment: It appears that your IDE doesn't recognize the namespaces of the classes. I'm talking about red letters and yellow highlighting. Make sure that you've ran composer install and that you have autoload file set up correctly.

Comment: Most likely the service is not public, so it can not be retrieved from the container. This is the default behavior, to discourage people from using ContainerAware too much, as it is regarded as a bad practice. You can check by adding the service name to `debug:container` or use `debug:autowiring` (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about the 'or' part of your error. You can use Symfony's dependency injection like this:

in Controller:

```
public function saveProfileEditAction(Request $request, FilterService $imagine) // Typehint service to controller method (remember to `use` on the top of the file)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $imagine->...; // Use it
```

In services.yml register your controller as a service and tag it so that symfony knows that it needs to inject it with services.

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    YourNamespace/*Bundle/Controller/YourController: // Change this
        tags: [ 'controller.service_arguments' ]
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example

Comment: Hi Domagoj, thanks for your response.  Do you know the syntax for specifying the arguments?  I went to https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html and it doesn't give an example of specifying Request as a service argument.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. Symfony knows what to do. You only need to tag your controller with `controller.service_arguments`. I've also added the part for the `_defaults` config. Set autowire and autoconfigure options to true

Comment: When you setup the project with Symfony 4 controllers should already have the tag and allow for this. Alternatively you can just inject the service into the Controller via constructor-injection or, if you use the AbstractController, overwrite the `public static getSubscribedServices`-array making the service available. For this just check the AbstractController + ControllerTrait where you can see how it is done for the default services like twig.

Comment: Hi Domagoj, that seemed to work.  I also had to add this to my services.yaml file:  Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService: '@liip_imagine.service.filter'

Comment: I was just about to tell you that. Glad it works. :)